# How to send scala post request with json data to Microsoft graph API

Tags: json, scala, http, microsoft-graph-api

I want to send mail using ms graph API from azure.
I know that first we need to authenticate azure app and generate a access token. And call send mail API to send mail.
I was able to generate access token.
But I am not able send mail with some message.

As graph API accept json we need to make our message in json.

How can I create a message with json and use it to send in post request using scala.

Comment: Well, just pick any HTTP client library and any JSON library that both play well together and that also integrates well with your current stack and then call the proper endpoint. Being a **Microsoft Graph** one changes nothing. If this is your first time doing an HTTP call in **Scala** or in any language then maybe try first doing a small PoC using any public API like **Postman Echo**, there should be plenty of guides / tutorials over there.

Comment: Hey, Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, I have tested from postman it worked fine. But from scala I did http call to generate token for send mail i am not able do so..

Comment: Okay so you should do is write a new question where you omit everything about **Microsoft Graph** and rather explain in detail, which library are you using to make the HTTP call, which problem you found, and be clear if it is a compile error, a runtime exception, or an unexpected result. Also, if possible try to minimize the problem, e.g using a public api, and / or removing authorization.